# HTTP Request Blocked by CORS Policy - JQUERY AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cors, sugarcrm

I have a google chrome extension that logs in from SUGAR-CRM using XMLHttpRequest and after that, I send another GET request for fetching users data with the OAuth-Token token in the header but I am getting the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://web-site/rest/v10/Users?order_by=first_name%3Aasc&max_num=1000&deleted=0&method=&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON' from origin 'https://mail.google.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

My rest call function is:

```
function dorestCall(url, type, method, data, success_callback, error_callback, complete_callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
            method: method,
            input_type: "JSON",
            response_type: "JSON",
            // rest_data: data //rest data
        },
        type: type, //GET Request
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            if (SUGAR.OAuthToken) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("OAuth-Token", SUGAR.OAuthToken);
            }
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (success_callback) {
                success_callback(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, error, errorThrown) {
            console.log("in error");
            if (error_callback) {
                error_callback(xhr, error, errorThrown);
            }
        },
        complete: function () {
            if (complete_callback) {
                complete_callback();
            }
        }
    });
 
}
```

My Request Headers are:

**Request URL**: https://site-url/rest/v10/Users?order_by=first_name%3Aasc&max_num=1000&deleted=0&method=&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON

**Referrer Policy**: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

**Accept**: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

**OAuth-Token**: ///token///

**Referer**: https://mail.google.com/

**User-Agent**: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36

**X-Requested-With**: XMLHttpRequest

**order_by**: first_name:asc

**max_num**: 1000

**deleted**: 0

**method**:

**input_type**: JSON

**response_type**: JSON

I have tried to set **dataType: "jsonp"**, **cors: true** and **headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',}** but nothing works for me.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set by the **server** to allow your client access to the resource - if not set by the server, then the server simply does not allow your client access - make the request using **your server** and it possibly will work

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin is already set by the server. Previously I have made a POST request from my chrome extension to get an O-Auth token that returned the status "OK" but now get_user and get_groups API is giving the error. Is there any issue with the rest Call function that is mentioned above or at the server-side?

Comment: does the server support `CORS preflight request` - because having `"OAuth-Token"` header will trigger a pre-flight `OPTIONS` request - if it's your server, you need to make sure you handle such method

Comment: This is a chrome extension that is integrated with Gmail, not a plain javascript code so I think Gmail is blocking the request. Can you tell me how to check if my server supports CORS preflight or not?

Comment: is it your server that is returning the `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status` error? if so, then it depends on your server code ... check t by checking you've implemented CORS correctly, just sending access-control headers for GET or POST isn't enough, you will have to handle the `OPTIONS` request correctly as well

Comment: I think that issue is related to Google Chrome because when I disable the "CORS for content scripts" from chrome://flags/#cors-for-content-scripts, everything starts working fine. Is there any possible solution so it works without disabling "CORS for content scripts"?

Comment: yes, don't make the request in a content script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223504/discussion-between-moeez-saiyam-and-jaromanda-x).